# How to update row entries of database table of specified column using PLSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am writing a SQL script file, that is run when i upgrade my software for some lower version to higher version. In the higher version of software their will be some database schema changes(that is one column is deleted and a one new column is added) now so far about altering the column of database and droping given column i don't face any issues both works fine.

But suppose the if i am on lower version and i have some data kept in my column that will be dropped form database in higher version and a new column is added to the database table, then i wanted to save my existing data into new column based upon certain condition on previous column in database by looping each row of database and checking previous column data for some conditions and based upon its  result i wanted to fill some new data to my new column that i had add in  higher version.

Once my existing data is save to new column i drop my column that i wanted to drop.

Eaxmple - Suppose my **higher vesrion database contains sequence_name** and **lower version database table contains sequence_id**.[image]

How to write a program to save the data stored in **sequence_id** to update fill data into **sequence_name** based upon some checks on **sequence_id** values.

I have written a SQL program for it but it didnt worked, my Code -

```
BEGIN
FOR i IN SELECT sequence_id FROM v_live_view_screen_config LOOP    
IF i.sequence_id <> -1 THEN
  DECLARE @seqname VARCHAR(30);
  INSERT INTO @seqname SELECT sequence_name FROM v_sequence_details WHERE 
sequence_id = i.sequence_id;     
   UPDATE v_live_view_screen_config
     SET sequence_name = @seqname;
     WHERE sequence_id = i.sequence_id;
     END IF;        
 END LOOP;
END;
```

I have tried this one also-

```
create procedure findsequenceId()
begin
Declare cSequenceID varchar(30);
Declare cConfigID INT;
Declare cSequenceName varchar(30);
Declare done int default false;
Declare curSeq cursor for select configID,seqID from liveview;
declare continue handler for not found set done = true;
open curSeq;
loop_seq: loop
fetch curSeq into cSequenceId, cConfigID;
if done then
        leave loop_seq;
end if;

select cSequenceName = seqName from seqDetails as m where m.seqID = 
cSequenceID;
update liveview set seqName = cSequenceName where seqID = cSequenceID;
end loop;
close curSeq;
end;
```

Please help i am little bit confused, my Database server MySQl.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this -
    UPDATE `v_live_view_screen_config` t2 ,( select 
    sequence_id,sequence_name from  `v_sequence_details` 
    ) t1 SET t2.sequence_name = t1.sequence_name WHERE 
    t1.sequence_id = t2.sequence_id;

May be this may work!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to provide a conceptual answer, but no code. You could create a new table with a temporary name that matches the new column structure you wish to achieve. Then, for each row in the old table, perform your logic and insert into the new table. Once you are complete, you will have all of your rows in the new table, with the logic having been performed on your column that was not JUST inserted (i.e., you converted all instances of value 'Foo' into 'Bar', but directly inserted all other values). Then drop your old table and rename the new table to the old table name. There may be a more elegant way to do it, but this is an easy brute force solution.